# Rails in Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I have my DocumentRoot for my virtualhost in Apache set up as the public dir of my rails app. The public dir contained the 'welcome aboard' rails index.html file, but i deleted it, created a controller called home, with the view 'index.' I then went into the config dir and uncommented root to: to point to home#index, but the website still just points to the public folder of the rails app, showing its contents. what did i do wrong?

home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

end
```

routes.rb

```
Webapp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "home/index"
  #Lots of comments
  root :to => "home#index"

end
```

**edit:**
I got passenger working I think, but the routes.rb isn't working. It's not making the root my newest controller i made with `rails generate controller home index`. Instead it's looking for index.html in the `public` dir, because when i put an index.html file in there, it shows it, and if i remove it, i get an error 500. furthermore the apache error.log says "Premature end of script headers:"

Comment: Did you create an action called `index` in your `HomeController`?

Comment: i don't know what an action is. i used rails generate controller home index. and i want my domain to point to that index view.

Comment: @hatorade could you post your `routes.rb` file and your `HomeController` code?

Comment: are you using something to make rails work in apache like passenger or are you simply pointing apache at the directory rails is in?  If you are just pointing it is only going to serve up the files that are in there.

Comment: Have you got this working without Apache yet? Rails comes with its own server, so you don't need to run it behind Apache if you're just developing your site locally

Comment: it's production (on a remote server)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the whole tree to your dev computer.  Run it with the development server 'script/server'

Just use passenger in production.

Comment: the rails app code would literally need to be in the prod server, though, right? so no matter what i have to solve THIS problem at some point.

Answer (score 0):

"Error 500" probably can be detailed a little more. Check your `log/production.log`.

Alternatively, try to sun Passenger in standalone mode to see if any error comes up. Shutdown Apache and run:

```
sudo passenger start -p 80
```

Something else I usually do: edit your `config/environments/production.rb` to report detailed error messages:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
```

Comment: nothing in log/production.log, passenger started in standalone mode.